# Django 1.4 How to customize elements inside MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I've set the widget on the `MultipleChoiceField` with:

```
self.fields['field_1'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=[(c.name, str(c)) for c in customers],
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        )
```

This ultimately spits out some html where each `choice` in `choices` gets an `<input>` in a `<label>` in an `<li>` in a `<ul>`.

I'd like to set a class on every `<li>`.  I need to remove the bullet point set next to each `<li>`, change the font size, maybe even style the checkbox.  Achievable with CSS selectors, but that strikes me as a code smell.

How can I do that?  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using Django 1.4?  That's an ancient version.

Comment: It is unfortunately not up to me.

Comment: upgrading Django is not that difficult.  not your fault, but it does reflect badly on the security priorities of whoever is running the show.

Comment: have you checked if you can use the [class attribute in the widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/)?  That should be available even in 1.4 days.  Whether or not that covers your needs is another thing, I grew somewhat frustrated with trying to style Django/Crispy forms myself.

Comment: I can set the class on the parent of what I want, or the child of the child of what I want, but there is abstracted nesting I can't figure out how to access.

Answer (score 0):

`widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'yourclassname multi-select'}`

I think this will add a class as in

```
<ul class="yourclassname multi-select">
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

then add css to that class name as, and to remove bullet point you have to just add this

```
.yourclassname 
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

Thanks! Hope it helps.